# vb.net convert multiple pdf files to excel using Bytescout pdf extractor

Tags: vb.net

i want to convert multiple pdf files into excel using bytescout pdf extractor can anyone help me with this. i am able to extract single pdf file.
however i am getting error while doing for multiple files.

here is the error what i am getting.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports Bytescout.PDFExtractor
    Imports System.IO

    Module Module1

    Sub Main()


        Try

            Dim extractor As New CSVExtractor()
            extractor.RegistrationName = "demo"
            extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo"

            'Dim filenames1 As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.TXT")
            For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\PDF Files\", "*.PDF", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

                extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(f)


                extractor.SaveCSVToFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\CSV Files\"(f))

                Console.WriteLine("Data has been extracted to CSV file....!" & Environment.NewLine)

            Next

            Thread.Sleep(3000)

        Catch error_t As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(error_t.ToString)
            Console.ReadKey(True)
        End Try


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].  `i am getting error` is not very useful to us; questions must include the actual error text in the question, some effort to resolve the problem and ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `the given path's format is not supported` could you please verify is the output path is correct? If the path folder or subfolder do not exist then you should create them first using `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the error by below code:

```
path = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\PDF Files\"
For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.PDF", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

    csvFileName = Replace(IO.Path.GetFileName(f), ".pdf", ".csv")
    extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(f)
    extractor.SaveCSVToFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\CSV Files\" & csvFileName)

    Console.WriteLine("Data has been extracted to CSV file....!" & Environment.NewLine)

Next
```

You need a file name to write to and the line below line does that.

```
csvFileName = Replace(IO.Path.GetFileName(f), ".pdf", ".csv")
```

Let us know if you need further help.

Thanks,
Prakash